# dynamic background-color not working in IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer, background-color, inline-formset

I need background-colors that change based on user input, but it isn't working in IE.

Am I doing it wrong? Is there a workaround?

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/3nx7G/1/

```
var viewModel = {
    color: ko.observable("red")
};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

<span style="background-color: red">red</span> <span style="background-color: green">green</span><br/>
<input data-bind="value: color" />
<span data-bind="text: color, style: { 'background-color': color }"></span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    Try using
   <span data-bind="text: color, style: { backgroundColor: color }"></span>.
```

Hyphen in the javascript is not valid use javascript equivalent
[like here](http://www.comptechdoc.org/independent/web/cgi/javamanual/javastyle.html)

Comment: I don't think your reason is correct since `'background-color'` is a string it's not evaluated by the JavaScript. Regardless, `backgroundColor` does work. Thanks!

Comment: As you are using in the data-bind for the knockout to apply bindings, it'll consider it as a javascript name. Good that worked..

Comment: No, if you look at the generated html it correctly has the `background-color`, IE just doesn't apply it: `<SPAN style="background-color: red" data-bind="text: color, style: { 'background-color': color }" __ko__1358358213391="ko2">red</SPAN>`

Comment: [link](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/style-binding.html) may be this will answer.

Comment: I still don't see how that applies. The HTML is the same in both cases: http://jsfiddle.net/3nx7G/3/ `<span style="background-color: red;" data-bind="text: color, style: { 'background-color': color }" __ko__1358359952587="ko2">
<span style="background-color: red;" data-bind="text: color, style: { 'backgroundColor': color }" __ko__1358359952587="ko3">`. Why does IE ignore the `background-color` on the first element but not the second?